# replace string before _ using awk or sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

i am writing a script which require me to replace word before `_` in a filename during listing. Details are below.

Sample input:

```
2017.12.01_07
2017.12.01_07
2017.12.01_06
2017.12.01_06
2017.12.01_05
2017.12.01_06
2017.12.01_05
2017.12.01_06
2017.12.01_08
```

I want to replace current date before `_` with 1 week old date

Date I want to replace with : - `DATE_SEC=$(date -d '7 day ago' +'%Y.%m.%d').`

Expected output :

```
2017.12.01_08 should change to 2017.11.24_08
```

Regards,

Dinesh

Comment: And are you looking to use the date 7 days before "today", whenever that day is, or 7 days before the date in the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU **`sed`** solution:

```
sed -En 's/\./-/g; s/^([^_]+)(_.*)/date -d"\1 + 1 week ago" +%Y.%m.%d\2/ep' file
```

The output:

```
2017.11.24_07
2017.11.24_07
2017.11.24_06
2017.11.24_06
2017.11.24_05
2017.11.24_06
2017.11.24_05
2017.11.24_06
2017.11.24_08
```

---

- `e` - this command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern space. If a substitution was made, the command that is found in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its output
- `p` - if the substitution was made, then print the new *pattern* space

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will do your work,

```
ls | awk -F'_' -v var=$(date -d '7 day ago' +'%Y.%m.%d') '{print var_$2}'
```

**Explanation:**

`ls` `-->` Here i used file listing option, we can change if required from a different source, say a file `FileList.txt`. then we can use `cat FileList.txt`

`|` `-->` Redirects the output of **ls** to **awk**

`-F` `-->` Sets the delimiter for `awk`

`-v var=` `-->` defines variable which can be used in `awk print`

`$2` `-->` prints the second field from the delimited out,

Answer (score 0):

**`Bash`** solution:

```
while read -r line; do
    d=${line%_*}
    sfx=_${line#*_}
    date -d"${d//./-} + 1 week ago" +%Y.%m.%d"$sfx"
done < file
```

The output:

```
2017.11.24_07
2017.11.24_07
2017.11.24_06
2017.11.24_06
2017.11.24_05
2017.11.24_06
2017.11.24_05
2017.11.24_06
2017.11.24_08
```